# How to detect colours and then apply colours while working with .xlsx(excel-2007) files on python 3.2(windows 7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel-2007, openpyxl

I am parsing .xlsx files using openpyxl.While writing into the xlsx files i need to maintain the same font colour as well as cell colour as was present in the cells of my input .xlsx files.Any idea how to extract the colour coding from the cell and then implement the same in another excel file.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can access the font colour by:
    colour = ws.cell(row=id,column=id).style.font.color

I am not sure how to access the cell colour though.